# keep getting error .Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in 'file path'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

i am adding a a mat-toolbar component into the app.component.html file of angular app and i keep getting error message

```
../node_modules/@angular/material/esm2015/bottom-sheet.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in 'C:\Users\liam\DBSTUF\codethemeanway\node_modules\@angular\material\esm2015'
```

ive tried adding different import statements such as

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';
```

i tried importing a module full of all of the material module imports

```
//material.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
```

anyone have this problem or know what it could be?

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have the `node_modules/@angular/animations` folder. If you don't have it, you probably need to install it via `npm install @angular/animations` and try again.

Every time you get an error like this, check your node dependencies and you will be fine ;)
Happy coding!